# Blur a round image around the edge

Tags: image, xaml, windows-10, uwp, blur

I am creating a Windows 10 mobile UWP app. I have a round image that i am trying to fade around the edge/border. There is a blurred background behind the image and I am trying create a look, that the image fades together with the blurred background.

XAML code of round/ellipse image:

```
<Ellipse Height="145"
         Width="145"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
         <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/test/card_picture_test.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
         </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

**Have not found any ways to blur an image around the border yet. Is this possible?**

(I have tried to solve this using Win2D but have neither managed to blur a round image or to blur an image only around edge/border.)

Help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Win2d would work: create two layers both containing your image - blur the first one, and then draw the second one on top of it using a radial gradient mask (center: visible, edges: masked).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what you're after by using two Ellipses.
One on top of the other, both have images inside.

```
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="500" Height="500">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="forest.JPG" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <Ellipse Width="500" Height="500">
                <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="forest.JPG" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>
                <Ellipse.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="10"/>
                </Ellipse.Effect>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
```

The Ellipse on top is totally blurred, the one underneath is normal.
From there, i gave the top (blurred) Ellipse an OpacityMask that causes the center of the blurred ellipse to be transparent and therefore reveal the non-blurred Elliptical image.

Now you can modify the degree of blur by changing the opacity mask of the top Ellipse's GradientStop Offset, as well as the BlurEffect's radius.

The Radius of the BlurEffect will change how blurry it is, and the offset of the GradientStops will change how far in the blur is allowed to go.

Comment: This solution won't work in UWP as there's no opacitymask, or effect.